# OK to say 'No' to 'Would you like to configure an Objective-C bridging header?' when first adding an existing Swift file?

Tags: swift, xcode

On the first attempt to add an existing Swift file to a Swift only Xcode project it states that adding this file will 'create a mixed Objective-C and Swift project' and asks 'Would you like to configure an Objective-C bridging header?'

But it isn't a mixed Objective C project. It was created from scratch as Swift only and has no Objective C code (well, none that I added anyway). And even if it does have some Objective-C (I guess the initial view controller that Xcode creates as a template inherits from an Objective-C class) then that means it was **always** a mixed project and adding another Swift file does not change that.

So, is it correct to say 'No' to this question?

Comment: If you have created swift only project it would not create Objective-C files(.h and .m). It will always have swift file and wouldn't ask to add Objective-C bridging header.

Comment: @Dipen that is what I would expect too. There are no .h nor .m files in the project, but when I first add (not create, add existing) a .swift file it **does** ask to add a bridging header. Hence my question.

Comment: You'r understanding is incorrect about initial `ViewController`, If you create a swift project it refers to `ViewController.swift` file and for Objective-C it refers to `ViewController.h and .m` file respectively. When you are targeting specific language you can select `No` for bridging header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to say No to this question. If you did want to use any Obj-C libraries (which is likely) then a bridging header is necessary and it does no harm to have one, you shouldn't see the prompt again.

It's unusual that the prompt is displaying at all, if there is no Obj-C in your code then it may be a bug. More likely if you're using a beta.

Comment: Thanks @ben. As it does no harm to have a bridging header, would you then recommend the safest default answer to this question is in fact 'Yes' then?

Comment: I can confirm that I said No (as discussed above, saying Yes should still be OK) and the app builds and works fine. It was a rebuild of a broken structure, so fairly mature and uploaded now for Beta testing.

Comment: Good to hear, you can always add one at a later date if you need Obj-C compatibility

Answer (score 0):

You only need the header when you actually want to make an Objective-C header available to your Swift code.